# how do free online OCR programs compare to commercial ones?

Tags: ocr

How much better would commercial OCR software be compared to the stuff that's available online for free?
More specifically: Reading text in pictures (things like book covers etc...)

Comment: To do what, exactly?  Handwriting recognition?  Type recognition?  Restoring old books, or letters?  Finding text in a picture of a street scene?

Comment: @mmr: Good point... edited to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with OCR quite a lot and can definitely vouch that the commercial offerings are much better than what you can find out there for free.   Yes, you can make a free one 'work', but it will take a lot of effort for sub-optimal results.

I recommend finding a product that uses the [ABBYY FineReader](http://www.abbyy.com) : It does a great job with little configuration.

You may want to consider whether you need to use an SDK provided by the OCR supplier or an end-user application.  The SDK will provide position details, etc of what it finds and offer a lot more in-depth control, but will be more expensive.   The end-user package will basically just read everything it finds, but you may be able to set it to automatic or control it rudimentally and it might be good enough for what you're trying to do, and may be a lot cheaper.

Get a trial version and give it a go!

Comment: By the way, there's an online OCR API powered by the ABBYY engine: http://www.wisetrend.com/wisetrend_ocr_cloud.shtml

Comment: i tried wisetrend ocr via the test email feature and it was disappointing. More than half the text was not read correctly .The image was simply some black courier text on a white background. Drawing some text that was reasonably neat and i would have expected readable in another image using paint was not scanned at all.

Answer (score 1):

[Google's ocropus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/) is free opensource and one of the best

Comment: I am not sure if that's google's. I think it is only hosted there; the team members don't even have google.com-email-addresses.

Comment: I thought it was the one Google had developed for it's book scanning project -  but I may be wrong

Comment: I should have done my homework better: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCRopus . While not developed by google, it is sponsored by them.